# openpyxl act differently in different Operating systems

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a python code producing report on xlsx format using openpyxl.
It starts with copying a template to a new file with different name, filling the data on it and finally save it with different name.
the template (which is in xlsx format of course) contains logo, when i run the code in Linux i get the output file with the logo as expected, but when i run the same code in Windows i get the output without the logo!

```
import openpyxl
import re
import shutil
import os
src = r'/app1/labreport_template.xlsx'
dst = r'/app1/labreport.xlsx'
shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

my_wb=openpyxl.load_workbook("app1/labreport.xlsx")
my_sheet = my_wb.active
##all selections and formatting run here##
##End_Of_Formatting_Output##
my_wb.save("/XP_2600/Reporting_21/labreport.xlsx")
zrc = r'/app1/labreport.xlsx'
dzz = r'/app1/' + idx + '.xlsx'
shutil.copyfile(zrc, dzz)
os.remove(zrc)
print('Successfully generated the report: ' + ' ' +  dzz )
```

Windows version just have Windows paths, everything else still same exact as Linux version, any idea whats wrong ? thanks.

Comment: it's hard to replicate the environmental condition. I looked at https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ , you need to have pillow `pip install pillow` installed while handling images. Maybe this is something you can explore.

Comment: Which versions of openpyxl do you have installed?

Comment: import openpyxl
print(openpyxl.__version__)
3.0.5
I don't have pillow installed on my Linux computer, and the code run well.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this by adding this:

```
##Logo_Entry
logo = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('logo.png')
logo.anchor = 'A1'
my_sheet.add_image(logo)
##Logo_End
```

Of course its not a solution, and i still wonder why openpyxl on Windows processing the file like this!,
but i add the workaround, maybe it help someone facing same issue.